# How to get value of a key inside an jsonb array in postgres and JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb, lateral

I have data that looks like inside a json table in postgres with a column called content has data similar to

```
{schd:[{key1:val1, key2:val2}]}
```

The way I extracted the key was

```
jsonb_array_elements('content'->'schd')->'key1'
```

However I cannot use this to join/on as I receive the error

```
ERROR:  argument of JOIN/ON must not return a set
```

I tried using LATERAL but I need clarification on whether this creates a cross join because the output does not look quiet right.

Are there any suggestions on other methods I should employ here.

Comment: Your JSON contains an array. If you (LATERAL) JOIN it, then it *may* duplicate your rows, because arrays can have multiple elements. It's a fact that you can't get around. If that creates unwanted duplication than it's sign, that maybe you don't want an array there at all.

Comment: *I tried using LATERAL but I need clarification on whether this creates a cross join* -- If you specifiy `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`, then it will create one (or `table1, LATERAL ...` that is a `CROSS JOIN` too)

Answer (score 0):

`{"Schd":["key1":"val1", "key2":"val2"]}` is not a valid Json because the keys in the array are not numeric.

If the array is in fact an object like `{"Schd":{"key1":"val1", "val1":"val2"}}` you can access `val1` with:

```
test=# SELECT '{"Schd":{"key1":"val1", "val1":"val2"}}'::json->'Schd'->'key1';
 ?column? 
----------
 "val1"
(1 row)
```

If its an array like `{"Schd":["val1", "val2"]}` you can access `val1` with:

```
test=# SELECT '{"Schd":["val1", "val2"]}'::json->'Schd'->0;
 ?column? 
----------
 "val1"
(1 row)
```

**Update:**

If the Json is `{"schd":[{"key1":"val1", "key2":"val2"}]}`, here is how to get `val1`:

```
test=# SELECT '{"schd":[{"key1":"val1", "key2":"val2"}]}'::json->'schd'->0->'key1';
 ?column? 
----------
 "val1"
(1 row)
```

Comment: I have edited the structure. I had a typo in there. Sorry about that!

Comment: It still does not let me do the join. I have the same error as before ERROR:  argument of JOIN/ON must not return a set